# Navigation Links Admin Panel with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, content-management-system

I'm attempting to try and create a sidebar within my dashboard CMS project that I am creating with Laravel with some different links to various pages. Some of these links require the logged in user to have a certain role to see them in the sidebar and even be able to visit them even if they try and access them directly.

I'm trying to figure out the sort of things I should be doing so that they can only see those certain pages based on their role_id and block them from seeing them if they try and visit the page directly.

My initial thought was to just try and put if statements everywhere but that just becomes more of a problem with the more I have different links.

Lets say I have the following roles and id's with those roles.

```
id - role_name 
1    basic user
2    editor
3    admin
4    super admin
```

Lets say I also have the following nav structure.

```
Dashboard
Category 1
    Link 1 
    Link 2
Category 2
    Link 3
    Link 4
    Link 5
    Link 6
Category 3
    Link 7
    Link 8
    Link 9
    Link 10
```

Is there a better way to handle navigation links with requirements of certain role ids than just putting a whole bunch of if statements all over my code?

Answer (score 2):

You can find similar functionality in LaraAdmin.
Check [LaraAdmin - Admin Panel for laravel](http://laraadmin.com). You can give permissions to Menu Modules
and Only Allowed Menus will be visible.